# Preventing developer access to Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-console

is there any way for a developer who has access to the Firebase console to be restricted access to the real-time database, preventing them from reading and writing any data directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you add a collaborator to the [`Users and permissions` panel](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/z2a-expenses/settings/iam) of the Firebase console, you can set what permissions they have. The defaults are <kbd>Owner</kbd>, <kbd>Editor</kbd>, and <kbd>Viewer</kbd>, with the latter granting read-only access to all (Firebase and Cloud) products in the console.

You can also choose <kbd>Assign Firebase role(s)</kbd>, in which case you can select per Firebase product what permission the user has. In this case you can exclude them from having access to the Firebase Realtime Database.